# Add element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul li` like this:

```
<ul class="NavMenu">
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add an icon in `li` element like this:

```
<ul class="NavMenu">
    <li><i class="myIcon"></i>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

How i can do this with jQuery?

Comment: `$('.NavMenu li').prepend('<i class="myIcon"></i>')`

Comment: `$('.NavMenu li:first').prepend($('<i />',{ class: 'myIcon' }));`

Comment: plz write whole code contain (document).ready(function(){ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code in your .js file

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.NavMenu li').prepend("<i class='myIcon'></i>");
 });`

Answer (score 1):

The **[prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)** method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**).

```js
$(".NavMenu li").prepend($("<i/>",{class:"myIcon",html:"&#x2661;"}));
console.log($(".NavMenu").html());
```

```css
.NavMenu li{list-style: none;}
.myIcon{color:red;padding-right:5px;font-size:20px;font-style: normal;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="NavMenu">
    <li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```